# Passing shell date and time value with spaces to Hive Script. Getting only date value in Hive Script

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am passing one Shell variable which contains date and time with space to Hive Script.

But i am only getting only date value while reading in Hive script. I want to send both date and time as string with single quotes to Hive Script.

Below is the Shell snippet

```
HQLSTARTTS=`date +%Y"-"%m"-"%d" "%H":"%M":"%S`
MAX_INCR_TIM=$(Select CAST(MAX(col) AS STRING) from tab_name;
HqlParams+=" -hiveconf ref_time='${MAX_INCR_TIM}' -hiveconf hqltim='${HQLSTARTTS}'

**above code will generate**
ref_time='2016-01-01 00:00:00'
hqltim='2018-01-01 00:00:00'
```

In HQL Script,

```
!echo ${hiveconf:ref_time} generate only '2016-01-01
!echo ${hiveconf:hqltim}  generate only '2018-01-01
```

Required Output

```
'2016-01-01 00:00:00'
'2018-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Can you please help me out on how to get both date and time in Hive Script?

Answer (score 0):

Use separate variables in hive command line:

```
hive -hiveconf ref_time="${MAX_INCR_TIM}" -hiveconf hqltim="${HQLSTARTTS}"

hive> ! echo ${hiveconf:ref_time};
2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

Or

put all of them into the file, say `HiveConf.hql` and use `source HiveConf.hql` hive command.